# MasterPage like concept in python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, master-pages

We are developing a web based application in python on google app engine platform. I have different pages in web site. What I want is to have a master page like functionality like we have in asp.net where I have just on template and all other pages will use that. How can I do this? I am a beginner in python

Answer (score 1):

I think you are exactly looking for "template extending".

1. Create base/master html file in "templates" folder.

   This will be base/master file where all theme css,js , html layout tags exists.
2. Add place holders for child html "content" in above base/master html

   `{% block content %}
   {% endblock %}`
3. Add following code line in "child" template to use above base/master html

   `{% extends 'path_to_base_html/base.html' %}
   {% block content %}
   Child html
   {% endblock %}`

Thanks to this nice tutorial,
http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/template_extending/index.html